# What to say when I contact my future advisor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, masters, advisor

I haven't officially been accepted to the program yet, but I needed to secure an advisor prior to applying. I was accepted by an advisor and she has been great with helping me fill out the application. However, I have yet to be accepted by the school. The school said they were waiting to hear the results of my funding, which I found out that I got. However, my person of interest then left to go away on a research expedition (and has little access to internet). I suspect she MAY be the reason my application is not moving forward right now. I have to select courses in less than a month. She suggested that we talk over the phone about courses when she comes back in a couple days.

I would like to send her an email the day she gets back, but what should I say in the email? Also, how should I bring up the fact that my application hasn't moved forward without complaining (or blaming her)?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Person of interest. Sorry, I reworded the question and took that out.

Comment: I also removed the tag POI because I don't think we really need such a new tag.

Comment: If she's set a date for you to talk, don't email,  just be patient and wait. The postgraduate application process is designed to be a gentle introduction to the bureaucracy and idiosyncrasies of academia.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to send an email, if you and her already agreed to talk over the phone. Anyway, I guess you can send an email as a reminder and to set up an agenda for the phone call.

I would just say something like:

> Dear NAME/TITLE/WHATEVER_IS_APPROPRIATE_IN_YOUR_CULTURE,
>
> I'm looking forward to our phone call on DATE at HOUR.
>
> Just so that we have a starting point for our conversation, I'd like to please get your advice on the courses I should take (the deadline for course selection is approaching soon).
>
> Also, I haven't heard any final word about my application from the department since DATE. I know you just got back from your research expedition, but I was wondering whether you have any update about the status of my application. Thank you in advance.
>
> Looking forward to talking to you soon,
>
> NAME

Comment: The thing is is we haven’t officially set up a time or date to talk. She just said we should talk when she gets back.